# How Can I Check My Neo4J License Status

Tags: neo4j

I'm building a new Azure VM that is going to run three instances of Neo4J. When I downloaded the trial version it ran with out a problem. I would run the following Powershell script

```
'C:\Data\Neo4j-1' |
Initialize-Neo4jServer `
 -ListenOnIPAddress 191.237.43.86 `
 -HTTPPort 7474 `
 -OnlineBackupServer '127.0.0.1:6362' `
 -PassThru |
Start-Neo4jServer -Console

'C:\Data\Neo4j-2' |
Initialize-Neo4jServer `
 -ListenOnIPAddress 191.237.43.86 `
 -HTTPPort 7475 `
 -ClearExistingDatabase `
 -OnlineBackupServer '127.0.0.1:6363' `
 -PassThru |
Start-Neo4jServer -Console

'C:\Data\Neo4j-3' |
Initialize-Neo4jServer `
 -ListenOnIPAddress 191.237.43.86 `
 -HTTPPort 7476 `
 -ClearExistingDatabase `
 -OnlineBackupServer '127.0.0.1:6364' `
 -PassThru |
Start-Neo4jServer -Console
```

Six command windows would open up, after a few seconds 1/2 of them would close and I would be left with the three instances listening on the same address but different ports.

My trial expired and suddenly all the windows would close on launch.

So I got a startup license for Neo4J. I first I thought they would just send me a license key to paste into a config file but they actually sent me a link to a fresh install of the whole program.

So I pasted the contexts into my three folders and ran the same script. Same results - they all closed after a few seconds.

Are there any logs I can look at to see why the instances are shutting down? Is there a command I can run to see what those three instances think their license status is? What am I missing?

Comment: This is not related to Neo4j licenses, must be sth with your Azure instances. Can you share the data/log/console.log and data/graph.db/messages.log files, if there are any errors?

Comment: Apparently the threat of going to Stack Overflow was enough because now it's loading just fine. I'll see if it stays working over the next few days.

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j server doesn't verify your license.

You need to purchase license for legal usage.

Comment: If you have a purchased license. Do you know how to check the licensing status?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the license files on the server, they are JWT WebTokens (at least true for the Bloom and GDS licenses), and decodable on the [JWT site](https://jwt.io/). The `exp` value in the payload section is the expiration date/time represented as an epoch timestamp in seconds.